# Ansible - multi-line variable from dict

Tags: ansible

Kia ora,

I have a Dict for users as follow, due to legacy and size of it I can't change the structure for now. Users can have none to multiple ssh-keys.

```yaml
users:
  - name: username
    comment: Gecos
    password: password hash
    quota: quota size
    uid: uid number
    ensure: present/absent
    ssh-keys:
    - type: ssh-rsa
      key: key1
      comment: key-comment
    - type: ssh-rsa
      key: key2
      comment: key-comment
```

For ssh key management I need to enforce the `exclusive` option of the `ansible.posix.authorized_key` module

Which says :

> Whether to remove all other non-specified keys from the authorized_keys file.
>
> Multiple keys can be specified in a single key string value by separating them by newlines.
>
> This option is not loop aware, so if you use with_ , it will be exclusive per iteration of the loop.
>
> If you want multiple keys in the file you need to pass them all to key in a single batch as mentioned above.

To do so I need to generate a multi-line variable from the ssh-keys dict for each users

With each key on a new line.

Here what is my idea for playbook

```yaml
- include_tasks: ssh_keys.yml
  loop: "{{ users }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: outer_item
```

ssh_keys.yml

```yaml
---
- name: Generate ssh-key list
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    user_sshkeys: HELP!!!

- name: Add SSH keys
  ansible.posix.authorized_key:
    user: "{{ outer_item.name }}"
    key: "{{ user_sshkeys }}"
    state: present
```

Here my previous version that doesn't manage the `exclusive` parameter.

```yaml
- name: Add SSH keys
  ansible.posix.authorized_key:
   user: "{{ item.0.name }}"
   key: "{{ item.1.type }} {{ item.1.key }} {{ item.1.comment }}"
   state: present
  loop: "{{ users|subelements('ssh-keys') }}"
  when: item.1.key is defined and item.0.ensure == 'present'
```

Cheers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the multi-line value for `key` using a template expression:

```
- name: Add SSH keys
  loop: "{{ users }}"
  ansible.posix.authorized_key:
    state: present
    exclusive: true
    user: "{{ item.name }}"
    key: |
      {% for key in item["ssh-keys"] %}
      {{ key.type }} {{ key.key }} {{ key.comment }}
      {% endfor %}
```

---

This playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    users:
      - name: username
        comment: Gecos
        password: password hash
        quota: quota size
        uid: uid number
        ensure: present/absent
        ssh-keys:
        - type: ssh-rsa
          key: key1
          comment: key-comment
        - type: ssh-rsa
          key: key2
          comment: key-comment
  tasks:
    - loop: "{{ users }}"
      ansible.posix.authorized_key:
        state: present
        exclusive: true
        user: "{{ item.name }}"
        key: |
          {% for key in item["ssh-keys"] %}
          {{ key.type }} {{ key.key }} {{ key.comment }}
          {% endfor %}
```

Will create `/home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys` with this content:

```
ssh-rsa key1 key-comment
ssh-rsa key2 key-comment
```

Answer (score 0):

Larsk answer is perfect, I found this version after posting, add it here for the extra condition on the loop.

```yaml
- include_tasks: ssh_keys.yml
  loop: "{{ users }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: outer_item
  when: outer_item['ssh_keys'] is defined and outer_item.ensure == 'present'
```

and

```yaml
- name: Extract SSH keys
  set_fact:
    ssh_keys: |
      {% for key in outer_item['ssh_keys'] %}
          {{ key['type'] }} {{ key['key'] }} {{ key['comment'] }}
      {% endfor %}

- name: Add SSH keys
  ansible.posix.authorized_key:
   user: "{{ outer_item.name }}"
   key: "{{ ssh_keys }}"
   exclusive: true
   state: present
```

I also updated my var file, `-` shouldn't be used for var names